# Why is my integer property not being serialized by BinaryFormatter?

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine

Was making a game on Unity, although I'm not sure if that matters for this question:

Create a `MyClass` object and set its integer width property to 100.

```
    MyClass obj         = new MyClass();
    obj.width = 100;
    BinaryFormatter bf  = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream file     = File.Create ("stuff.dat");
    bf.Serialize(file, obj);
    file.Close();
```

---

Load it.

```
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream file = File.Open("stuff.dat");
    MyClass obj = (MyClass)bf.Deserialize(file);
    file.Close();
```

The width property is at its default, 0, rather than 100.

---

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[System.Serializable]
public class MyClass {

    public  int             width           = 0;
    public  int             height          = 0;

}
```

---

Why is that?

Comment: My crystal ball can tell that this *width* property was not originally part of the class, the indent is screwed up.  Using binary serialization is tricky, it is not version tolerant unless you do something like apply the [NonSerialized] attribute so the old data can still be loaded.  That worked.

Comment: `obj.width = 100;` … `bf.Serialize(file, data);` — are you sure? What's correct, `obj` or `data`?

Comment: @OndrejTucny yeah sorry, I had to simplify the snippet. But the problem is the same.

Comment: @HansPassant: The property has always been part of the class, I just have weird indentation tendencies.

Comment: Well, that was worth a shot.  It's not like anything else can explain it :)

Comment: It looks good, I'm pretty sure the problem isn't in this part of the code. Couple of questions: is width the only property that is being reset to it's default value after deserilization? Have you checked "stuff.dat", maybe using a hex viewer to check if the correct values were written out? (if the whole class hierarchy is not too complex) Have you checked where else is this property referenced in the code? Could you post the rest of the code for this class? (or a link to it)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is like 2 months old but I want to give it a proper answer for anyone else that might stumble upon this question if that's okay?

It's important to note that when you create a "new" version of a class, it is a 'new' version. So say in another class, you do a MyClass mycla = new MyClass(); and set the width mycla.width = 100; Then you go into another class and do a MyClass mycla = new MyClass(); and try to use mycla.width, the width will return to the default value that has been assigned in the main variable list.

This is why you should use an object to represent the data inside a class that you wish to serialize. The object reference of the class contains saved information about its variables which have been changed from their default values.

This is how I am handling saving in my current game and it's performing well to the gamers:

```
    using UnityEngine;
        using System.Collections;
        using System;
        [Serializable]
        public class MyClass 
        {
            public static MyClass saveObj;
            public  int width = 0;
            public  int height = 0;
}
    //(please use another script to perform these saving and loading operations):


    public void Save()
    {
        MyClass obj = new MyClass();
        obj.width = 100;
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Create ("stuff.dat");
        bf.Serialize(file, obj);
        file.Close();
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Open("stuff.dat");
        MyClass.saveObj = (MyClass)bf.Deserialize(file);
        file.Close();
        print(MyClass.saveObj.width);
    }
```